# Spark + Amazon S3 "s3a://" urls

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

AFAIK, the newest, best S3 implementation for Hadoop + Spark is invoked by using the "s3a://" url protocol. This works great on pre-configured Amazon EMR.

However, when running on a local dev system using the pre-built `spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz`, I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 99 more
```

Next I tried to launch my Spark job specifying the hadoop-aws addon:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master local \
    --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 \
    my_spark_program.py
```

I get

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

    :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0!jsr305.jar

    :: org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.4!avro.jar

    :: org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.4.1!snappy-java.jar(bundle)

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I made a dummy build.sbt project in a temp directory with those three dependencies to see if a basic sbt build could successfully download those and I got:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.4: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.4 {compile=[default(compile)]}:
[error]     org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.4!avro.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.pom
[error]     org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.4!avro.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.pom
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:
[error]     com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0!jsr305.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0/jsr305-3.0.0.pom
[error]     com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0!jsr305.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0/jsr305-3.0.0.pom
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.4.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.4.1 {compile=[default(compile)]}:
[error]     org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.4.1!snappy-java.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.4.1/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.pom
[error]     org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.4.1!snappy-java.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.4.1/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.pom
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Sep 2, 2016 6:47:17 PM
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: have you tried adding those other dependencies to sbt?

Comment: I added the three dependencies that are causing errors to an otherwise empty sbt project and that failed to build. Why would adding other dependencies be useful or helpful?

Comment: I was just curious. Obviously adding the AWS hadoop package thinks that it needs to download those others, so that's why it's useful / helpful to try to explicitly ask for them in the project

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need additional jars in your submit flag. The Maven repository has a number of AWS packages for Java which you can use to fix your current error: https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=aws

I continuously receive headaches with the S3A filesystem error; but the aws-java-sdk:1.7.4 jar works for Spark 2.0.

Further dialogue on the matter can be found here; albeit there is indeed an actual package in the Maven AWS EC2 repository.

https://sparkour.urizone.net/recipes/using-s3/

Try this:

```
spark-submit --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 my_spark_program.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache Spark (that is: I'm ignoring the build Amazon ship in EMR), you need to add a dependency on `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws` for exactly the same version of Hadoop that the rest of spark uses. This adds the S3a FS and the transitive dependencies. The version of the AWS SDK *must* be the same as that used to build the `hadoop-aws` library, as it's a bit of a moving target.

See: [Apache Spark and Object Stores](http://www.slideshare.net/steve_l/apache-spark-and-object-stores)