# I am try to load the data from s3 bucket, but i am not able to load

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

i am trying to load the data from s3 bucket into spark
the code i am using

```
package com.spark.example

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Logger,Level}


object S3IOTest {
  def main (arg: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().
      master("local").
      appName("demoApp").
      getOrCreate()
    val accessKeyId = System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    val secretAccessKey = System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secretAccessKey)
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
//    val data = spark.read.option("header",true).option("inferschema",true).csv("data/flight-data/csv/2011-summary.csv")
//    data.show(5)
    val data = spark.read.option("iferschema",true).csv("s3n://examplelake/sparkinput/*.csv")
    data.take(5).foreach(println)
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

can you please help me with this, if you want more information i can give you.

the error i am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/crypto/key/KeyProviderTokenIssuer
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2565)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2576)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2593)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2632)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2614)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:332)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:618)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:467)
at com.spark.example.S3IOTest$.main(App.scala:25)
at com.spark.example.S3IOTest.main(App.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyProviderTokenIssuer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 33 more
```

why the keyprovidertokenissuer is missing. do we need any thing to configure in the maven pom.xml file.

this is the pom.xml file i am using

```
<properties>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11.8</scala.compat.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    <spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-project -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-project</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>hadoop-cloud_2.11</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>${spark.version}</version>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-cloud -->
<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>spark-cloud_2.11</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>${spark.version}</version>-->
<!--&lt;!&ndash;      <version>2.1.0.2.6.0.3-8</version>&ndash;&gt;-->

<!--    </dependency>-->


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
<!--      <scope>compile</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
<!--      <scope>compile</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>mysql</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>5.1.42</version>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Any errors? And the code runs on lambda, ec2 or ecs?

Comment: i am running that in my local machine

Comment: i have attached the error in the question

Comment: Can you show sbt or maven libraries ?

Comment: hi i have attached the maven dependencies in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below dependency. Also change "iferschema" to "inferschema".
this link might further help you. [Spark + Amazon S3 "s3a://" urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301997/spark-amazon-s3-s3a-urls)

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
 <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
 <version>1.11.327</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing below dependency in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```